# React Native: How to set height of the child view same as parent view with position=absolute?

Tags: react-native

I want to show two children views inside a parent view. Both the children have position: "absolute" in style, as I want to apply some animations on the position of the views. I want to set the height of the views to be equal to the parent view. How can I achieve this in React native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have your children views that use absolute positions the same height as the parent, you can set their `top` and `bottom` position to 0.

Then you can still apply a `margin` or `transform` to further change their position.

```js
var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.child1}/>
        <View style={styles.child2}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  child1: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 40,
  },
  child2: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: 40,
  },
});
```

[image: sample]

See it live: https://rnplay.org/apps/kSZnBg

Comment: This is one way of doing it. However, it makes it necessary for the views to be aligned exactly with parents borders like top: 0 and bottom: 0 all the time. This will prevent me from doing animations where the position of the children is changed. I have mentioned this requirement in my question.

Comment: No you can still apply a margin or transform, as stated in my answer.